# Error "exit signal Bus error (7)" How to continue after making a backtrace?

Tags: php, apache

I have a Centos Server in 1and1 with Apache, Magento, MagentoBooster and Xcache installed.

The server usually (1-8 times per day) prints this error "exit signal Bus error (7)" and sometimes this causes Apache not to respond.

I have made a backtrace with GDB, but I don't know how to continue.

> gdb /usr/sbin/httpd core.XXXX --batch --quiet -ex "thread apply all bt full" > backtrace.log

The backtrace:

```
[New Thread 15312]
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Core was generated by `/usr/sbin/httpd'.
Program terminated with signal 7, Bus error.
#0  0x00002abcf6c7324e in memcpy () from /lib64/libc.so.6

Thread 1 (Thread 0x2abcf8c72300 (LWP 15312)):
#0  0x00002abcf6c7324e in memcpy () from /lib64/libc.so.6
No symbol table info available.
#1  0x00002abd02e6b9c7 in ?? () from /usr/lib64/php/modules//php_ioncube_loader_lin_5.2_x86_64.so
No symbol table info available.
#2  0x00002abd02ed4d47 in _zval_dup () from /usr/lib64/php/modules//php_ioncube_loader_lin_5.2_x86_64.so
No symbol table info available.
#3  0x00002abd02ecdffb in ?? () from /usr/lib64/php/modules//php_ioncube_loader_lin_5.2_x86_64.so
No symbol table info available.
#4  0x00002abd02c32636 in xc_compile_file (h=0x7fffc3e7e4f0, type=2) at /opt/xcache-1.3.2-rc1/xcache.c:1060
        __orig_bailout = 0x7fffc3e88f10
        __bailout = {{__jmpbuf = {46991244125792, 3379122525071325456, 46991369192208, 140736480142576, 140736480142656, 46991244125792, 3379207471940512272, 
              3379122524988693332}, __mask_was_saved = 0, __saved_mask = {__val = {46991369228841, 46991369206800, 46991369195208, 46991382361728, 
                46991369196536, 46991369206984, 46991369210744, 0, 46991240130544, 140733193388033, 0, 140736480142296, 46991240361284, 46991369207528, 
                46991369232128, 3}}}}
        sandbox = {alloc = 0, 
          filename = 0x2abd078dd0e0 "/var/www/vhosts/DOMAIN/httpdocs/var/ait_rewrite/67b58abff9e6bd7b400bb2fc1903bf2f.php", 
          orig_included_files = {nTableSize = 256, nTableMask = 255, nNumOfElements = 191, nNextFreeElement = 0, pInternalPointer = 0x2abcf4da53d0, 
            pListHead = 0x2abcf4da53d0, pListTail = 0x2abd07dfeb28, arBuckets = 0x2abd0896d690, pDestructor = 0, persistent = 0 '\000', nApplyCount = 0 '\000', 
            bApplyProtection = 1 '\001'}, tmp_included_files = 0x2abd0069e830, orig_zend_constants = 0x2abd0d630b60, tmp_zend_constants = {nTableSize = 2048, 
            nTableMask = 2047, nNumOfElements = 1559, nNextFreeElement = 0, pInternalPointer = 0x2abd08283760, pListHead = 0x2abd08283760, 
            pListTail = 0x2abd08320810, arBuckets = 0x2abd08302aa0, pDestructor = 0x2abd02c34850 <xc_free_zend_constant>, persistent = 1 '\001', 
            nApplyCount = 0 '\000', bApplyProtection = 1 '\001'}, orig_function_table = 0x2abd0d61f340, orig_class_table = 0x2abd0d61f2b0, 
          orig_auto_globals = 0x2abd0d618910, tmp_function_table = {nTableSize = 2048, nTableMask = 2047, nNumOfElements = 1555, nNextFreeElement = 0, 
            pInternalPointer = 0x2abd08320ce0, pListHead = 0x2abd08320ce0, pListTail = 0x2abd0933fe60, arBuckets = 0x2abd079c8500, 
            pDestructor = 0x2abd0033e1d0 <zend_function_dtor>, persistent = 1 '\001', nApplyCount = 0 '\000', bApplyProtection = 0 '\000'}, tmp_class_table = {
            nTableSize = 16, nTableMask = 15, nNumOfElements = 0, nNextFreeElement = 0, pInternalPointer = 0x0, pListHead = 0x0, pListTail = 0x0, 
            arBuckets = 0x2abd079dbf60, pDestructor = 0x2abd0033dcf0 <destroy_zend_class>, persistent = 1 '\001', nApplyCount = 0 '\000', 
            bApplyProtection = 0 '\000'}, tmp_auto_globals = {nTableSize = 16, nTableMask = 15, nNumOfElements = 9, nNextFreeElement = 0, 
            pInternalPointer = 0x2abd0933ffc0, pListHead = 0x2abd0933ffc0, pListTail = 0x2abd093403e0, arBuckets = 0x2abd09340470, pDestructor = 0, 
            persistent = 1 '\001', nApplyCount = 0 '\000', bApplyProtection = 0 '\000'}, tmp_internal_constant_tail = 0x2abd08320810, 
          tmp_internal_function_tail = 0x2abd0933fe60, tmp_internal_class_tail = 0x0, orig_user_error_handler_error_reporting = 8191}
        op_array = <value optimized out>
        xce = {type = XC_TYPE_PHP, hvalue = 2460, next = 0x2abd0d939e60, cache = 0x2abd0d90b038, size = 10, refcount = 46991369191320, hits = 4, 
          ctime = 46991362335072, atime = 8, dtime = 46991240673248, ttl = 46991369192096, name = {lval = 46991363920096, dval = 2.3216818564143281e-310, str = {
              val = 0x2abd078dd0e0 "/var/www/vhosts/DOMAIN/httpdocs/var/ait_rewrite/67b58abff9e6bd7b400bb2fc1903bf2f.php", len = 107}, 
            ht = 0x2abd078dd0e0, obj = {handle = 126734560, handlers = 0x2abd0000006b}}, data = {php = 0x7fffc3e7e440, var = 0x7fffc3e7e440}, 
          have_references = 0 '\000'}
        stored_xce = 0x0
        php = {sourcesize = 8947, device = 64769, inode = 9907963, mtime = 1353055102, op_array = 0x2abd00344004, constinfo_cnt = 1, constinfos = 0x0, 
          funcinfo_cnt = 132120232, funcinfos = 0x8, classinfo_cnt = 8, classinfos = 0x0, have_early_binding = 168 '\250', autoglobal_cnt = 10941, 
          autoglobals = 0x8}
        cache = 0x2abd0d90b038
        catched = <value optimized out>
        filename = <value optimized out>
        opened_path_buffer = "\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000I\032\065\000\275*\000\000\300\347i\000\275*\000\000\001\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\377\377\377\377\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\003\000\000\000[\337\227\337,\002pr\n\000\000\000\000\000\000\000P\323\347\303\377\177\000\000\357\367\220\b\275*\000\000\243\002M\a\275*\000\000\005", '\000' <repeats 15 times>"\357, \367\220\b\275*\000\000\244\002M\a\275*\000\000Du0\000\275*\000\000\b\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\232b=\365\000\000\000\000\002\000\000\000\377\177\000\000\005\000\000\000\275*\000\000\220\322\347\303\377\177\000\000\000\020\000\000\000\000\000\000,\324\347\303\377\177\000\000`\321\347\303^", '\000' <repeats 27 times>, "\f\000\000 \001", '\000' <repeats 11 times>"\260, \322\347\303", '\000' <repeats 12 times>, "P\323\347\303\377\177\000\000x\225\332\364\004\000\000\000\001\000\000\000\031\000\000\000\300\331\336\a\275*\000\000\300\331\336\a\275*\000\000"...
        old_constinfo_cnt = 1559
        old_funcinfo_cnt = 1555
        old_classinfo_cnt = 0
#5  0x00002abd003290bf in compile_filename () from /etc/httpd/modules/libphp5.so
No symbol table info available.
#6  0x00002abd00398ded in ?? () from /etc/httpd/modules/libphp5.so
No symbol table info available.
#7  0x00002abd0036628c in execute () from /etc/httpd/modules/libphp5.so
No symbol table info available.
#8  0x00002abd0033b796 in zend_call_function () from /etc/httpd/modules/libphp5.so
No symbol table info available.
#9  0x00002abd0035b1e1 in zend_call_method () from /etc/httpd/modules/libphp5.so
No symbol table info available.
#10 0x00002abd00273bf4 in zif_spl_autoload_call () from /etc/httpd/modules/libphp5.so
No symbol table info available.
#11 0x00002abd0033b945 in zend_call_function () from /etc/httpd/modules/libphp5.so
No symbol table info available.
#12 0x00002abd0033c51e in zend_lookup_class_ex () from /etc/httpd/modules/libphp5.so
No symbol table info available.
#13 0x00002abd0033c728 in zend_fetch_class () from /etc/httpd/modules/libphp5.so
No symbol table info available.
#14 0x00002abd003a61ab in ?? () from /etc/httpd/modules/libphp5.so
No symbol table info available.
#15 0x00002abd0036628c in execute () from /etc/httpd/modules/libphp5.so
No symbol table info available.
#16 0x00002abd00366b91 in ?? () from /etc/httpd/modules/libphp5.so
No symbol table info available.
#17 0x00002abd0036628c in execute () from /etc/httpd/modules/libphp5.so
No symbol table info available.
#18 0x00002abd00366b91 in ?? () from /etc/httpd/modules/libphp5.so
No symbol table info available.
#19 0x00002abd0036628c in execute () from /etc/httpd/modules/libphp5.so
No symbol table info available.
#20 0x00002abd00366b91 in ?? () from /etc/httpd/modules/libphp5.so
No symbol table info available.
#21 0x00002abd0036628c in execute () from /etc/httpd/modules/libphp5.so
No symbol table info available.
#22 0x00002abd00366b91 in ?? () from /etc/httpd/modules/libphp5.so
No symbol table info available.
#23 0x00002abd0036628c in execute () from /etc/httpd/modules/libphp5.so
No symbol table info available.
#24 0x00002abd00366b91 in ?? () from /etc/httpd/modules/libphp5.so
No symbol table info available.
#25 0x00002abd0036628c in execute () from /etc/httpd/modules/libphp5.so
No symbol table info available.
#26 0x00002abd00366b91 in ?? () from /etc/httpd/modules/libphp5.so
No symbol table info available.
#27 0x00002abd0036628c in execute () from /etc/httpd/modules/libphp5.so
No symbol table info available.
#28 0x00002abd00366b91 in ?? () from /etc/httpd/modules/libphp5.so
No symbol table info available.
#29 0x00002abd0036628c in execute () from /etc/httpd/modules/libphp5.so
No symbol table info available.
#30 0x00002abd00366b91 in ?? () from /etc/httpd/modules/libphp5.so
No symbol table info available.
#31 0x00002abd0036628c in execute () from /etc/httpd/modules/libphp5.so
No symbol table info available.
#32 0x00002abd00366b91 in ?? () from /etc/httpd/modules/libphp5.so
No symbol table info available.
#33 0x00002abd0036628c in execute () from /etc/httpd/modules/libphp5.so
No symbol table info available.
#34 0x00002abd00366b91 in ?? () from /etc/httpd/modules/libphp5.so
No symbol table info available.
#35 0x00002abd0036628c in execute () from /etc/httpd/modules/libphp5.so
No symbol table info available.
#36 0x00002abd00366b91 in ?? () from /etc/httpd/modules/libphp5.so
No symbol table info available.
#37 0x00002abd0036628c in execute () from /etc/httpd/modules/libphp5.so
No symbol table info available.
#38 0x00002abd00346943 in zend_execute_scripts () from /etc/httpd/modules/libphp5.so
No symbol table info available.
#39 0x00002abd00306898 in php_execute_script () from /etc/httpd/modules/libphp5.so
No symbol table info available.
#40 0x00002abd003cb09d in ?? () from /etc/httpd/modules/libphp5.so
No symbol table info available.
#41 0x00002abcf4cfca0a in ap_run_handler ()
No symbol table info available.
#42 0x00002abcf4cffe98 in ap_invoke_handler ()
No symbol table info available.
#43 0x00002abcf4d0a74a in ap_internal_redirect ()
No symbol table info available.
#44 0x00002abcfdb45bf0 in ap_make_dirstr_parent () from /etc/httpd/modules/mod_rewrite.so
No symbol table info available.
#45 0x00002abcf4cfca0a in ap_run_handler ()
No symbol table info available.
#46 0x00002abcf4cffe98 in ap_invoke_handler ()
No symbol table info available.
#47 0x00002abcf4d0a8f8 in ap_process_request ()
No symbol table info available.
#48 0x00002abcf4d07b30 in ?? ()
No symbol table info available.
#49 0x00002abcf4d03c92 in ap_run_process_connection ()
No symbol table info available.
#50 0x00002abcf4d0e7a9 in ?? ()
No symbol table info available.
#51 0x00002abcf4d0ea3a in ?? ()
No symbol table info available.
#52 0x00002abcf4d0f29d in ap_mpm_run ()
No symbol table info available.
#53 0x00002abcf4ce9e48 in main ()
No symbol table info available.
```

Can anyone help me?

### ADITIONAL INFO

php -v

> PHP 5.2.10 (cli) (built: Nov 13 2009 11:44:05) Copyright (c) 1997-2009 The PHP Group
>
> Zend Engine v2.2.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2009 Zend Technologies
>
> with XCache v1.3.2-rc1, Copyright (c) 2005-2011, by mOo
>
> with the ionCube PHP Loader v3.1.28, Copyright (c) 2002-2007, by ionCube Ltd.

httpd -v

> Server version: Apache/2.2.3
>   Server built:   May  4 2011 06:51:15

Apache modules:

> core prefork http_core mod_so mod_auth_basic mod_auth_digest mod_authn_file mod_authn_alias mod_authn_anon mod_authn_dbm mod_authn_default mod_authz_host mod_authz_user mod_authz_owner mod_authz_groupfile mod_authz_dbm mod_authz_default util_ldap mod_authnz_ldap mod_include mod_log_config mod_logio mod_env mod_ext_filter mod_mime_magic mod_expires mod_deflate mod_headers mod_usertrack mod_setenvif mod_mime mod_dav mod_status mod_autoindex mod_info mod_dav_fs mod_vhost_alias mod_negotiation mod_dir mod_actions mod_speling mod_userdir mod_alias mod_rewrite mod_proxy mod_proxy_balancer mod_proxy_ftp mod_proxy_http mod_proxy_connect mod_cache mod_suexec mod_disk_cache mod_file_cache mod_mem_cache mod_cgi mod_version mod_fcgid mod_perl mod_php5 mod_proxy_ajp mod_python mod_ssl

Aditional modules:

> dbase
>
> ionCube Loader
>
> sysvsem
>
> sysvshm

### EDIT (November 18)

I have disabled some suspicious modules and the error persist. The new backtrace:

```
[New Thread 12403]
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Core was generated by `/usr/sbin/httpd'.
Program terminated with signal 7, Bus error.
#0  0x00002b0c5754a24e in memcpy () from /lib64/libc.so.6

Thread 1 (Thread 0x2b0c59549300 (LWP 12403)):
#0  0x00002b0c5754a24e in memcpy () from /lib64/libc.so.6
No symbol table info available.
#1  0x00002b0c558519c7 in ?? () from /usr/lib64/php/modules//php_ioncube_loader_lin_5.2_x86_64.so
No symbol table info available.
#2  0x00002b0c558bad47 in _zval_dup () from /usr/lib64/php/modules//php_ioncube_loader_lin_5.2_x86_64.so
No symbol table info available.
#3  0x00002b0c558b3ffb in ?? () from /usr/lib64/php/modules//php_ioncube_loader_lin_5.2_x86_64.so
No symbol table info available.
#4  0x00002b0c60d650bf in compile_filename () from /etc/httpd/modules/libphp5.so
No symbol table info available.
#5  0x00002b0c60dd4ded in ?? () from /etc/httpd/modules/libphp5.so
No symbol table info available.
#6  0x00002b0c60da228c in execute () from /etc/httpd/modules/libphp5.so
No symbol table info available.
#7  0x00002b0c60d77796 in zend_call_function () from /etc/httpd/modules/libphp5.so
No symbol table info available.
#8  0x00002b0c60d971e1 in zend_call_method () from /etc/httpd/modules/libphp5.so
No symbol table info available.
#9  0x00002b0c60cafbf4 in zif_spl_autoload_call () from /etc/httpd/modules/libphp5.so
No symbol table info available.
#10 0x00002b0c60d77945 in zend_call_function () from /etc/httpd/modules/libphp5.so
No symbol table info available.
#11 0x00002b0c60d7851e in zend_lookup_class_ex () from /etc/httpd/modules/libphp5.so
No symbol table info available.
#12 0x00002b0c60d78728 in zend_fetch_class () from /etc/httpd/modules/libphp5.so
No symbol table info available.
#13 0x00002b0c60de21ab in ?? () from /etc/httpd/modules/libphp5.so
No symbol table info available.
#14 0x00002b0c60da228c in execute () from /etc/httpd/modules/libphp5.so
No symbol table info available.
#15 0x00002b0c60da2b91 in ?? () from /etc/httpd/modules/libphp5.so
No symbol table info available.
#16 0x00002b0c60da228c in execute () from /etc/httpd/modules/libphp5.so
No symbol table info available.
#17 0x00002b0c60da2b91 in ?? () from /etc/httpd/modules/libphp5.so
No symbol table info available.
#18 0x00002b0c60da228c in execute () from /etc/httpd/modules/libphp5.so
No symbol table info available.
#19 0x00002b0c60da2b91 in ?? () from /etc/httpd/modules/libphp5.so
No symbol table info available.
#20 0x00002b0c60da228c in execute () from /etc/httpd/modules/libphp5.so
No symbol table info available.
#21 0x00002b0c60da2b91 in ?? () from /etc/httpd/modules/libphp5.so
No symbol table info available.
#22 0x00002b0c60da228c in execute () from /etc/httpd/modules/libphp5.so
No symbol table info available.
#23 0x00002b0c60da2b91 in ?? () from /etc/httpd/modules/libphp5.so
No symbol table info available.
#24 0x00002b0c60da228c in execute () from /etc/httpd/modules/libphp5.so
No symbol table info available.
#25 0x00002b0c60da2b91 in ?? () from /etc/httpd/modules/libphp5.so
No symbol table info available.
#26 0x00002b0c60da228c in execute () from /etc/httpd/modules/libphp5.so
No symbol table info available.
#27 0x00002b0c60da2b91 in ?? () from /etc/httpd/modules/libphp5.so
No symbol table info available.
#28 0x00002b0c60da228c in execute () from /etc/httpd/modules/libphp5.so
No symbol table info available.
#29 0x00002b0c60da2b91 in ?? () from /etc/httpd/modules/libphp5.so
No symbol table info available.
#30 0x00002b0c60da228c in execute () from /etc/httpd/modules/libphp5.so
No symbol table info available.
#31 0x00002b0c60da2b91 in ?? () from /etc/httpd/modules/libphp5.so
No symbol table info available.
#32 0x00002b0c60da228c in execute () from /etc/httpd/modules/libphp5.so
No symbol table info available.
#33 0x00002b0c60da2b91 in ?? () from /etc/httpd/modules/libphp5.so
No symbol table info available.
#34 0x00002b0c60da228c in execute () from /etc/httpd/modules/libphp5.so
No symbol table info available.
#35 0x00002b0c60da2b91 in ?? () from /etc/httpd/modules/libphp5.so
No symbol table info available.
#36 0x00002b0c60da228c in execute () from /etc/httpd/modules/libphp5.so
No symbol table info available.
#37 0x00002b0c60da2b91 in ?? () from /etc/httpd/modules/libphp5.so
No symbol table info available.
#38 0x00002b0c60da228c in execute () from /etc/httpd/modules/libphp5.so
No symbol table info available.
#39 0x00002b0c60d82943 in zend_execute_scripts () from /etc/httpd/modules/libphp5.so
No symbol table info available.
#40 0x00002b0c60d42898 in php_execute_script () from /etc/httpd/modules/libphp5.so
No symbol table info available.
#41 0x00002b0c60e0709d in ?? () from /etc/httpd/modules/libphp5.so
No symbol table info available.
#42 0x00002b0c555d3a0a in ap_run_handler ()
No symbol table info available.
#43 0x00002b0c555d6e98 in ap_invoke_handler ()
No symbol table info available.
#44 0x00002b0c555e174a in ap_internal_redirect ()
No symbol table info available.
#45 0x00002b0c5e41cbf0 in ap_make_dirstr_parent () from /etc/httpd/modules/mod_rewrite.so
No symbol table info available.
#46 0x00002b0c555d3a0a in ap_run_handler ()
No symbol table info available.
#47 0x00002b0c555d6e98 in ap_invoke_handler ()
No symbol table info available.
#48 0x00002b0c555e18f8 in ap_process_request ()
No symbol table info available.
#49 0x00002b0c555deb30 in ?? ()
No symbol table info available.
#50 0x00002b0c555dac92 in ap_run_process_connection ()
No symbol table info available.
#51 0x00002b0c555e57a9 in ?? ()
No symbol table info available.
#52 0x00002b0c555e5a3a in ?? ()
No symbol table info available.
#53 0x00002b0c555e629d in ap_mpm_run ()
No symbol table info available.
#54 0x00002b0c555c0e48 in main ()
No symbol table info available.
```

Comment: Given it's occuring in memcpy(), this should be relevant: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segmentation_fault

Answer (score 1):

You have probably badly compiled ioncube extension. Try to recompile this extension.

Comment: I didn't compile ioncube, it was already in the Centos image. Anyway I have start from zero in another server and for the moment I haven't got any problem.